# Paypal API issues

Tags: php, paypal

I am using Paypal and got a few questions actually.

1. My IPN script is not getting called. I've tried it with the IPN simulator, and just put a simple error log that writes to a file, and it doesn't write when the simulator runs, it gives a success message although when I visit it manually, it does successfully log.

Here is the IPN script:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors',TRUE);
ini_set('html_errors',FALSE);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'/ipn_errors.log');          
error_log('CALLED');
```

I've set the form variables as so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="*SELLER EMAIL*">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Mr Strong T-Shirt">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="XQk0tZm0OavuvAP0gmxRdntLUpsmwZfiE%2FzjunlSAeN4F73sgzXjyVaclgY6nfvoKRyqrZICW3z5beEcs693lA%3D%3D">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="3.00">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://*WEBSITE URL*/success/">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://*WEBSITE URL*/buy/ipn">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

*WEBSITE URL* is NOT local, its hosted online and accessible.

1. The 'seller' will vary, as it's a selling platform. Can I set a return URL without having to enable it on each seller account?

Any idea? Help is always much appreciated.

Comment: Can you email me your IPN URL? Email is in my profile. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set up "return" without having to enable it on each seller's account.

When the buyer will complete the purchase, he will need to click on the link "Return to Merchant website" as the redirect won't be automatic.

If merchants wants to enable AutoReturn (which works only for buyers that pay with Login), they will need to access to Profile in their PayPal account in order to set it up.

Ref. [AutoReturn](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/ProfileAndTools/#id08A9E900IEX)

Comment: With regard to IPN instead, you can submit the variable "notify_url" however in order to setup IPN correctly, I'd recommend to follow the guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. Just to confirm, there is no way to enable 'AutoReturn' without having to change a setting in each users account? As the site will act as a 'platform', this is not viable.

Comment: "AutoReturn" must be switched it on manually in each account.

Comment: For a platform, we have more flexible solutions available such as Adaptive Payments or even Express Checkout, which lets you act as solely the API caller, get the IPN POST yourself and set a specified account as the receiver. Our Payments Standard product really wasn't designed for this. While you may be able to make it work, it's not an ideal solution and the user (and merchant) experience is worse for it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with IPN before:

So here are the following things that I did:

Check if paypal IPN sends notification to my notify_url using IPN Simulator

```
a.)Your page should allow paypal IPN notification

b.) Your notify_url link is correct
```

If all are met above and IPN is still not working then there should be problem a problem in your configuration check your paypal configuration for validating IPN

Not this using port:80

```
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://'. $url_parsed['host'], '80', $err_num, $err_str, 30);
```

But this using port:443

```
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://'. $url_parsed['host'], '443', $err_num, $err_str, 30);
```

And that should fix all for paypal's IPN notification.

Please take note also that there's a problem with IPN notification not working in sandbox see my reference before here (a bit old but in the same year)

Hope it all helps you

Comment: Your page should allow paypal IPN notification - what do you mean by  this? I haven't even started to process/check the data, all the notify url doing is logging 'CALLED'. Although, when I run it through the simulator, it is not logged, although when I manually go to the page, it does write to log. The notify_url is correct too. I'm using sandbox. Any advice is much appreciated, thanks for your help!

Comment: if you want to run your IPN , use IPN simulator. IPN works after the transaction happened in paypal and the user didn't return to your market. That's the time where IPN works

Comment: When I've tested it in the IPN simulator, it doesn't get called for some reason. 'CALLED' does not get logged when I use the simulator, but does when I go to the page manually. :S

Comment: dont test using localhost

Comment: the url inputted in IPN simulator is your notify_url?

Comment: @RyanGittings, and it's not working when using IPN simulator? Check your access log, check your security if you have made one and last is check your script

Answer (score 0):

Problem sorted! There was a login validation which kept redirecting it to login, stripped this out and it worked fine. Few.